# auto refresh url in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a django app that fetches and displays error messages for the past 15 minutes stored in a MONGOdb. I want to add auto refreshing url option so that the messages are displayed after every 10 minutes irrespective of any new error being there or not. How can this be done using django? any package available?

Comment: you need to think about how a web page works. to refresh the page every 10 minutes you need to use Javascript. there's nothing Django can do here

Comment: You should read about http and its request and response cycle as well as its statelesness...

Comment: @Anentropic not entirely true; OP could use [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are of course entirely correct :)  still no Django involved though

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to update the page. JS sends ajax request to a django view that returns json response, or maybe part of the html, not the whole page. Then JS can append that result to the page.

Something like this (jQuery sample):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/errors/list/",
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#container").html(data);
});
```

And in view you can do something like this too.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def list_view(request):
    errors = Error.objects.all()
    return render(request, "errors/list.html", {'errors': errors})
```

template would only render the part of the page that should be updated (e.g. the list of errors), not the whole html page

```
{% for error in errors %}
   <div>{{ error }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you only want to refresh the page in browser, you can use jQuery too to do it.

```
location.reload();
```

You may want to check `jQuery.ajax` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).